MAUI app development on macOS: `dotnet workload restore` causes MSBuild.InvalidProjectFileException
I cloned a repo which has a MAUI project in it. When I open it in VS4Mac the project shows as greyed (not loaded) and with a warning icon. When I click the icon with my mouse it shows a tooltip saying "Project requires .NET workloads to be installed", then I right click on the project and I can see a menu command called "Install .NET Workloads". I click on it, it asks me my macOS password (I assume to gain privileges to install the workloads system-wide). But then, nothing happens. No progress bar. No output pane showing me anything. I wait 5 minutes, 10 minutes... No result. The warning icon is still there. I close VS4Mac, I open it again. Same thing: warning icon. I try to install workloads again. Same story.
Ok, I resort to the command line: I go to the root of the repo and type dotnet workload restore and this is the result:
Unhandled exception: Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The imported project "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.421/Xamarin/Mac/Xamarin.Mac.FSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.421/Xamarin/Mac/Xamarin.Mac.FSharp.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  /Users/knocte/Documents/Code/geewalletMASTERclean/src/GWallet.Frontend.XF.Mac/GWallet.Frontend.XF.Mac.fsproj
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject(String errorSubCategoryResourceName, IElementLocation elementLocation, String resourceName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject[T1,T2](IElementLocation elementLocation, String resourceName, T1 arg0, T2 arg1)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpression(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, String unescapedExpression, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError, List`1& imports)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, List`1& projects, SdkResult& sdkResult, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImports(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, SdkResult& sdkResult)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate()
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate(IEvaluatorData`4 data, Project project, ProjectRootElement root, ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Int32 maxNodeCount, PropertyDictionary`1 environmentProperties, ILoggingService loggingService, IItemFactory`2 itemFactory, IToolsetProvider toolsetProvider, ProjectRootElementCacheBase projectRootElementCache, BuildEventContext buildEventContext, ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, Int32 submissionId, EvaluationContext evaluationContext, Boolean interactive)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.Initialize(ProjectRootElement xml, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String explicitToolsVersion, String explicitSubToolsetVersion, Int32 visualStudioVersionFromSolution, BuildParameters buildParameters, ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext buildEventContext, ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, Int32 submissionId, Nullable`1 projectLoadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection, Nullable`1 projectLoadSettings, EvaluationContext evaluationContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String toolsVersion)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Workloads.Workload.Restore.WorkloadRestoreCommand.RunTargetToGetWorkloadIds(IEnumerable`1 allProjects)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Workloads.Workload.Restore.WorkloadRestoreCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.WorkloadRestoreCommandParser.<>c.<ConstructCommand>b__2_0(ParseResult parseResult)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.ParseResultCommandHandler.Invoke(InvocationContext context)
   at System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<<BuildInvocationChain>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<<UseHelp>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c.<<UseSuggestDirective>b__18_0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<<UseParseDirective>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.CommandLine.CommandLineBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<<UseExceptionHandler>b__0>d.MoveNext()

How to run MAUI apps on a macOS system?

The command-line was the way to go, but I was placed in the wrong directory.
Once I placed myself in the directory where the MAUI project is (instead of the repo's root, where only one sln file can be found), then it worked:
% sudo dotnet workload restore
Password:

Welcome to .NET 6.0!
---------------------
SDK Version: 6.0.421

Telemetry
---------
The .NET tools collect usage data in order to help us improve your experience. It is collected by Microsoft and shared with the community. You can opt-out of telemetry by setting the DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to '1' or 'true' using your favorite shell.

Read more about .NET CLI Tools telemetry: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-telemetry

----------------
Installed an ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate.
To trust the certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust' (Windows and macOS only).
Learn about HTTPS: https://aka.ms/dotnet-https
----------------
Write your first app: https://aka.ms/dotnet-hello-world
Find out what's new: https://aka.ms/dotnet-whats-new
Explore documentation: https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs
Report issues and find source on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/core
Use 'dotnet --help' to see available commands or visit: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Installing workloads: maui-maccatalyst maui-ios

Workload(s) 'maui-maccatalyst maui-ios' are already installed.
Skipping NuGet package signature verification.
Installing workload manifest microsoft.net.sdk.tvos version 16.4.60…
Installing workload manifest microsoft.net.sdk.android version 32.0.509…
Installing workload manifest microsoft.net.sdk.maui version 6.0.553…
Installing workload manifest microsoft.net.sdk.macos version 13.3.60…
Installing workload manifest microsoft.net.sdk.maccatalyst version 16.4.60…
Installing workload manifest microsoft.net.sdk.ios version 16.4.60…
Installing workload manifest microsoft.net.workload.mono.toolchain version 6.0.29…
Installing workload manifest microsoft.net.workload.emscripten version 6.0.29…
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.maccatalyst version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.maccatalyst version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.maccatalyst version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.maccatalyst version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.maccatalyst version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.maccatalyst version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.maccatalyst version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.maccatalyst version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.maccatalyst version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.maccatalyst version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.maccatalyst version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.maccatalyst version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Dependencies version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Dependencies version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Sdk version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Sdk.net6 version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Extensions version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Extensions version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Graphics version 6.0.501...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Graphics version 6.0.501...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Templates.net6 version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Templates.net6 version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.any version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.any version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.any version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.any version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.any version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.any version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.any version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.any version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.any version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.any version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Sdk version 16.4.60...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Sdk.net6 version 16.4.60...
Installing pack Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Ref version 16.4.60...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Ref version 16.4.60...
Installing pack Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Runtime.maccatalyst-arm64 version 16.4.60...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Runtime.maccatalyst-arm64 version 16.4.60...
Installing pack Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Runtime.maccatalyst-x64 version 16.4.60...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Runtime.maccatalyst-x64 version 16.4.60...
Installing pack Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Templates version 16.4.60...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Templates version 16.4.60...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.osx-x64.Cross.maccatalyst-arm64 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net6.maccatalyst-arm64 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.osx-x64.Cross.maccatalyst-x64 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net6.maccatalyst-x64 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.maccatalyst-arm64 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net6.maccatalyst-arm64 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.maccatalyst-x64 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net6.maccatalyst-x64 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task.net6 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoTargets.Sdk version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoTargets.Sdk.net6 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.ios version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.ios version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.ios version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.ios version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.ios version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.ios version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.ios version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.ios version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.ios version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.ios version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.ios version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.ios version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.iOS.Sdk version 16.4.60...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.iOS.Sdk.net6 version 16.4.60...
Installing pack Microsoft.iOS.Ref version 16.4.60...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.iOS.Ref version 16.4.60...
Installing pack Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.ios-arm version 16.4.60...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.ios-arm version 16.4.60...
Installing pack Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.ios-arm64 version 16.4.60...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.ios-arm64 version 16.4.60...
Installing pack Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.iossimulator-x86 version 16.4.60...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.iossimulator-x86 version 16.4.60...
Installing pack Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.iossimulator-x64 version 16.4.60...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.iossimulator-x64 version 16.4.60...
Installing pack Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.iossimulator-arm64 version 16.4.60...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.iossimulator-arm64 version 16.4.60...
Installing pack Microsoft.iOS.Templates version 16.4.60...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.iOS.Templates version 16.4.60...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.osx-x64.Cross.ios-arm version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net6.ios-arm version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.osx-x64.Cross.ios-arm64 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net6.ios-arm64 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.osx-x64.Cross.iossimulator-arm64 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net6.iossimulator-arm64 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.osx-x64.Cross.iossimulator-x64 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net6.iossimulator-x64 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.osx-x64.Cross.iossimulator-x86 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net6.iossimulator-x86 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.ios-arm version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net6.ios-arm version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.ios-arm64 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net6.ios-arm64 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.iossimulator-arm64 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net6.iossimulator-arm64 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.iossimulator-x64 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net6.iossimulator-x64 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.iossimulator-x86 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net6.iossimulator-x86 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.android version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.android version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.android version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.android version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.android version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.android version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.android version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.android version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.android version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.android version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.android version 6.0.553...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.android version 6.0.553...
Installing pack Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Darwin version 32.0.509...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Android.Sdk.net6 version 32.0.509...
Installing pack Microsoft.Android.Ref.31 version 32.0.509...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Android.Ref.31 version 32.0.509...
Installing pack Microsoft.Android.Runtime.31.android-arm version 32.0.509...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Android.Runtime.31.android-arm version 32.0.509...
Installing pack Microsoft.Android.Runtime.31.android-arm64 version 32.0.509...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Android.Runtime.31.android-arm64 version 32.0.509...
Installing pack Microsoft.Android.Runtime.31.android-x86 version 32.0.509...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Android.Runtime.31.android-x86 version 32.0.509...
Installing pack Microsoft.Android.Runtime.31.android-x64 version 32.0.509...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Android.Runtime.31.android-x64 version 32.0.509...
Installing pack Microsoft.Android.Templates version 32.0.509...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.Android.Templates version 32.0.509...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-arm version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net6.android-arm version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-arm64 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net6.android-arm64 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x64 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net6.android-x64 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x86 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.net6.android-x86 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.osx-x64.Cross.android-x86 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net6.android-x86 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.osx-x64.Cross.android-x64 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net6.android-x64 version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.osx-x64.Cross.android-arm version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net6.android-arm version 6.0.29...
Installing pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.osx-x64.Cross.android-arm64 version 6.0.29...
Writing workload pack installation record for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.net6.android-arm64 version 6.0.29...
Garbage collecting for SDK feature band(s) 6.0.400 7.0.200 7.0.100...
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.ios version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.maccatalyst version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.maccatalyst-arm64 version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.android version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.ios-arm64 version 15.4.447…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.ios version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Dependencies version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x86 version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.ios-arm version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.ios-arm64 version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.any version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Resizetizer.Sdk version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.iossimulator-x86 version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.iossimulator-x86 version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.maccatalyst-arm64 version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Sdk version 15.4.447…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Android.Runtime.31.android-x86 version 32.0.448…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Sdk version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.android-x64 version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.android version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.maccatalyst version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Runtime.maccatalyst-arm64 version 15.4.447…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Android.Ref.31 version 32.0.448…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.ios-arm version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.ios version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.ios version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Android.Runtime.31.android-arm version 32.0.448…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.iossimulator-x86 version 15.4.447…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.maccatalyst-x64 version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Graphics version 6.0.403…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.android version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Runtime.maccatalyst-x64 version 15.4.447…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-arm version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.iOS.Ref version 15.4.447…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.ios version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.any version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Maui version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.iossimulator-arm64 version 15.4.447…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.maccatalyst version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.maccatalyst-x64 version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.android version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Ref version 15.4.447…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Extensions version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Android.Runtime.31.android-arm64 version 32.0.448…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.iossimulator-arm64 version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Ref.any version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-arm64 version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.any version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.ios-arm64 version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.iossimulator-arm64 version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Templates-6.0 version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.iOS.Templates version 15.4.447…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.maccatalyst version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoAOTCompiler.Task version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Core.Ref.maccatalyst version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.iossimulator-x64 version 15.4.447…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.android-arm version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.android version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.iossimulator-x64 version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Android.Sdk version 32.0.448…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.android-x86 version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Android.Runtime.31.android-x64 version 32.0.448…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.iOS.Sdk version 15.4.447…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.android-arm64 version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.maccatalyst version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Android.Templates version 32.0.448…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NET.Runtime.MonoTargets.Sdk version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.iOS.Runtime.ios-arm version 15.4.447…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Core.Runtime.any version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Runtime.ios version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Essentials.Runtime.android version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Ref.any version 6.0.486…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.MacCatalyst.Templates version 15.4.447…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.AOT.Cross.iossimulator-x64 version 6.0.8…
Uninstalling workload pack Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x64 version 6.0.8…

Successfully installed workload(s) maui-maccatalyst maui-ios maui-android maccatalyst android.

